# Yii2 -active record - Group where condition

Tags: php, yii2

I need to write query which looks like this:

**(WHERE metrics = kg && quantity < xx) || (WHERE metrics = lbs && quantity < (xx * 2.2046) )**

Is this possible to do with Yii Active Record, and if how?

Comment: How are you planning on using this? The answer depends on this.

Comment: I need to find every record that is less then the search quantity. But quantity can be in lbs or kg, and user can have metrics set to lbs or kg. So if he search for less then 100kg, that is also less then 222lbs. I need to get both results...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many options depending on how you want use the [query builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#where). Here are a few:

1) You could plug in the condition as a string:

```
Product::find()->where("(metrics = 'kg' AND quantity < :quantity) 
                   OR (metrics = 'lbs' AND quantity < :quantity_lbs))",
                   [":quantity" => $quantity, ":quantity_lbs" => $quantity * 2.2]
              )->all();
```

2) Or split the condition by the `OR`:

```
Product::find()->where("(metrics = 'kg' AND quantity < :quantity)") 
               ->orWhere("(metrics = 'lbs' AND quantity < :quantity_lbs)")
               ->addParams([":quantity" => $quantity, ":quantity_lbs" => $quantity * 2.2])
               ->all();
```

3) Or use [operators](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#operator-format):

```
Product::find()->where(['metrics' => 'kg', ['<', ['quantity' => $quantity]]]) 
               ->orWhere(['metrics'=> 'lbs', ['<', ['quantity' => $quantity * 2.2]]]) 
               ->all();
```

I'd go with the second option. It's the most readable and is easier to maintain.